# Alterning images in beamer is shifting to right

Tags: image, latex, beamer

When I am trying to do alternating images in beamer with usage of the **\only** and **overlayarea** like this:

```
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Tasks}

    \begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{\textheight}
        \begin{figure}
            \centering
            \only<1>
                {
                    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{img/noise_detail_2.png}
                }
            \only<2>
                {
                    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{img/noise_detail_2.png}
                }
            \only<3>
                {
                    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{img/noise_detail_2.png}
                }
            \only<4>
                {
                    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{img/noise_detail_2.png}
                }
        \end{figure}
    \end{overlayarea}      
\end{frame}
```

the image is moving to the right more and more on the each slide. Let's say, that in the 1. slide is in the position *x*, in the second slide in the position *x+5* and in the third slide *x+10*.

Why? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You have what is referred to as a spurious space between usages of `\only`. While spreading out your code for readability purposes might work well, sometimes these spaces cause unwanted output in your resulting PDF. [Use `%` to keep the readability but avoid the spacing issues](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/5764):

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Tasks}

  \begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{\textheight}
    \begin{figure}
      \centering
      \only<1>
        {%
          \includegraphics[width=.8\textwidth]{example-image-a}%
        }%
      \only<2>
        {%
          \includegraphics[width=.8\textwidth]{example-image-b}%
        }%
      \only<3>
        {%
          \includegraphics[width=.8\textwidth]{example-image-c}%
        }%
    \end{figure}
  \end{overlayarea}      
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```